# Common java code for different android flavors

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

There are 5 flavors of Android app.

class Sample.java that is the same for 4 but different for 1.

I believe I cannot put the same class both in the main folder and in the flavor folder.

So now I have to maintain 4 copies of the exact same class for those 4 flavors.

Is there any way that I could do with keeping just two versions of this class?

Comment: Use a combination of Flavors and build types

Comment: See this answer [StackOverflow 28563632][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28563632/common-code-for-different-android-flavors