# Tell Gradle to check two directories for main java source code

Tags: java, gradle

I have a project full of tests that we use to query our environments. We run these tests using Gradle. I would like to run these tests from a standalone application to get rid of the Gradle dependency. I am using the gradle 'application' plugin and trying to run the JUnit tests using JUnitCore and everything is fine except I can't access my test classes from main.

I have

```
--main
--smokeTest
--longRunningTest
```

When I tell Gradle this it doesn't work.

```
sourceSets {
 main {
    java { srcDirs ['src/main/java', 'src/smokeTest/java'] }
    }
}
```

It says "main" is not a recognized function. The java plugin is installed because I already have entries to define smokeTest and longRunningTest.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a linked source folder in Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947314/how-to-add-a-linked-source-folder-in-android-studio)

Comment: Have you tried just leaving off the `main` declaration and seeing where that'll get you?

Comment: try adding "=" after "srcDirs".

Comment: Where is this statement located? top level? or inside another statement?

Answer (score 13):

Not to steal the flame from @david-m-karr, just refining a bit:

```
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/smokeTest/java']
```

might work

Comment: Writing a proper answer is preferred in this case, so upvoting this - it's also much clearer to read an example given in an answer than in a comment.