# Handling minor differences in build variants

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have an application with 2 product flavors and as a result 4 build variants:

```
1) freeDebug
2) freeRelease
3) paidDebug
4) paidRelease
```

I have a `Fragment` that contains an ad, and it takes 2 lines to implement:

```
@Nullable @BindView (R.id.bottomsheet_ad) AdView mAdView;
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

So because of 2 lines, I have to potentially maintain 2 or more files.

I'm considering 2 solutions:

1) Check flavor at runtime:

```
if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("flavor123")) {
    ...
}
```

2) Create a common flavor and point needed variants in gradle, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30548238/7915814):

```
android {
    ...
    productFlavors {
        flavorOne {
            ...
        }
        flavorTwo {
            ...
        }
        flavorThree {
            ...
        }
        flavorFour {
            ...
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        flavorOne.java.srcDir 'src/common/java'
        flavorTwo.java.srcDir 'src/common/java'
        flavorThree.java.srcDir 'src/common/java'
    }
}
```

Which solution would be better? And is checking flavor at runtime as above considered polluting the code?

Comment: IMHO, a better option than those two is to use `buildConfigField` to define a custom flag in your Gradle script, then branch your code based on that flag. In other words, do not depend on `BuildConfig.FLAVOR`, but `BuildConfig.DO_WE_SHOW_AN_AD_HERE`.

Comment: If your only concern is about this `Ad`, I'd use stubs and provide an empty impl per flavor (and wouldn't bother making the project more complicated). But it really depends on so many factors it's hard to tell. I wouldn't do the `if` in the code. Or as suggested above ^ use buildConfig flags (tho I usually use these to turn features off for debug, not per flavor)

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks a lot for the suggestion, I'll give it a go, looks like a more neat way to do it.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini That's a really nice option, I haven't thought of that. I'll try CommonsWare's suggestion and this one as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add something like following to appropriate flavor in your `build.gradle`

```
buildConfigField "boolean", "showAds", 'true'
```

And then use like following (your main src files will still be used for additional flavors you add):

```
if (BuildConfig.showAds) {

}
```

Comment: Looks like a clean way to do it! Thank you! I just have a small, maybe stupid question, is this technique something you would use in a "production ready" application?

Comment: I'm using it here fwiw.  Seems to be a common enough pattern.

Comment: That's a valid point :D Thanks a lot for the answer again, will definitely use it!

Comment: This is a valid pattern. Do not abuse it :)

Comment: @MartinMarconcini I'll try not too :D But would it be possible to change those values and remove the ads if the apk is decompiled, or am I thinking too much?

Comment: @MartinMarconcini That is all I needed to hear :D thank you!